# Selecting top result of each category of product

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Below query is pulling back the data below.

[image]

I am trying to only return one single result for each product number, with only the highest orddate, and it related order total (ordttl) and unit cost (ucost).

Ideas on implementing? Thanks for any responses.

```
SELECT
ordln.pnum as 'Product Number',
prod.name as 'Product Name',
ordhd.snum,
sup.name,
ordhd.ordttl,
ORDHD.onum,
ORDHD.orddate,
ordln.ucost
FROM
scmdb.dbo.cksprodm prod (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN scmdb.dbo.cksordln ordln (NOLOCK) on prod.pnum = ordln.pnum
INNER JOIN scmdb.dbo.cksordhd ordhd (NOLOCK) on ordhd.onum = ordln.onum
LEFT JOIN scmdb.dbo.ckssuplr sup (NOLOCK) on ordhd.snum = coalesce(sup.snum, 
sup.asnum)
WHERE ordhd.orddate BETWEEN 
DATEADD(month,-6,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) + '06:00') AND 
GETDATE() -- order date is between 6 months ago and today.
AND ordln.pnum NOT IN (SELECT distinct PNUM 
                    FROM scmdb.dbo.cksquohd qhd 
                    inner join scmdb.dbo.cksquoln qln on qhd.quote = qln.quote
                    where qhd.qedate > GETDATE() 
                  )
```

Comment: either use join over row_number or cross apply on top 1

Comment: Can there be ties? If so, how should they be handled?

Comment: @HABO It's highly unlikely to occur since the orddate includes time as well. If they did occur it, selecting one of the results arbitrarily would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use row_number to rank by date and get latest date's row:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
    ordln.pnum as 'Product Number',
    prod.name as 'Product Name',
    ordhd.snum,
    sup.name,
    ordhd.ordttl,
    ORDHD.onum,
    ORDHD.orddate,
    ordln.ucost,
    row_number() over (partition by ordln.pnum order by ORDHD.orddate desc) as ranking
    FROM
    scmdb.dbo.cksprodm prod (NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN scmdb.dbo.cksordln ordln (NOLOCK) on prod.pnum = ordln.pnum
    INNER JOIN scmdb.dbo.cksordhd ordhd (NOLOCK) on ordhd.onum = ordln.onum
    LEFT JOIN scmdb.dbo.ckssuplr sup (NOLOCK) on ordhd.snum = coalesce(sup.snum, 
    sup.asnum)
    WHERE ordhd.orddate BETWEEN 
    DATEADD(month,-6,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,getdate()),0) + '06:00') AND 
    GETDATE() -- order date is between 6 months ago and today.
    AND ordln.pnum NOT IN (SELECT distinct PNUM 
                        FROM scmdb.dbo.cksquohd qhd 
                        inner join scmdb.dbo.cksquoln qln on qhd.quote = qln.quote
                        where qhd.qedate > GETDATE() 
                      ) 
) t
where ranking = 1
```

Comment: Very simple solution. Thank you.